How can I create this background using a gradient instead of an image?
the current code is below


.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 382px;
  background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/Jn6J3qN/card.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: сontain;
  flex-basis: 382px;
  min-height: 218px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 32px;
}
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>




What have you actually tried? Where are you stuck? There already a lot of question concerning gradients here on SO

What is the problem with using one of the solutions suggested here How do you make a gradient background in css?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_images/Using_CSS_gradients

Have a play with diagonal gradients see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Images/Using_CSS_gradients

Just set .item background linear-gradient and also set parameters for it.
You can use this colour picker tools, like this website: https://cssgradient.io/, to set linear-gradient parameters.


.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}
.item {
  flex-basis: 382px;
  background: rgb(12,28,87);
  background: linear-gradient(156deg, rgba(12,28,87,1) 0%, 
  rgba(83,81,147,1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: сontain;
  flex-basis: 382px;
  min-height: 218px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  padding: 32px;
}
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>




.wrap {
  display: flex;
  gap: 30px;
}
.item {
  padding: 30px;
  flex-basis: 382px;
  background: rgb(12,28,87);
  background: linear-gradient(156deg, rgba(12,28,87,1) 0%, 
  rgba(83,81,147,1) 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: сontain;
  flex-basis: 382px;
  min-height: 218px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}


Perhaps explain what you did, and show it in a snippet (copy snippet to answer and update with your CSS)

Please explain how this would solve the issue. Code-only answers are not good answers
